# How to use Python ParDo in a Java pipeline?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a Python code for data analysis and I want to embed it inside a much bigger pipeline which is written in Apache Beam Java SDK.
I know that there is also a Python SDK but I don't know how to combine between them.

How can it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently not supported. It is a great idea, and something that is being considered. Much of the work on the in-progress portability API has the potential to enable this, but there is no estimate for when it will actually be possible.